# I can't build the inherited Apple Watch app

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, apple-watch

I'm facing significant issues trying to build an Apple Watch app written in Swift, created by the previous developer, both on Xcode's simulator and on a real device(Apple Watch via iPhone). I'm encountering various errors, and the build wouldn't successful.

Here's an overview of the app:

・The app is created using WatchKit.

・It uses Firebase to store data measured on the Apple Watch.

Some of the issues I'm encountering include:

・Missing specified libraries.

・The message "double-quoted include "~~~" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead" won't disappear.

I've been researching and trying various methods to resolve the issues, but new problems keep arising. Even worse, I can't get in touch with the previous developer.

I've attempted the following solutions so far, but none have resolved the problems:

・Editing the Podfile.

・Adding libraries in TARGETS > General > Frameworks and Libraries.

・Setting "Quoted include in..." to No in project > Pods > Build Settings.

The issues and solutions mentioned here are just a part of the problem, and various other issues are arising. This is my first time developing with Xcode, and I suspect I may have made some basic configuration errors. I would greatly appreciate any guidance or insights you can provide, so please feel free to share any suggestions you may have.